# How can I increment input time field [hh:mm:ss] by seconds by default?

Tags: jquery, html, input

I am using an input field setup like the below to capture duration data with the format hh:mm:ss.

```
<input type="time" step="1" min="00:00:00" max="23:59:59" value="00:00:00" class="time"/>
```

Since many of the durations to be captured are likely to be in seconds, I would like the arrows to control the seconds portion of the time when the user clicks the arrows.

Currently, by default, the arrows are bringing the hour portion into focus and stepping this, even when a duration of 00:00:01 is entered.

Is there a way to force the focus on the seconds portion upon clicking of the input / arrows?

Any help / suggestions as always would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you look at an implementation of Google Chrome. AFAIK, there are no ways to change the behavior of the spin button provided by Chrome.  So, you need to

1. Hide the Chrome-provided spin button, and
2. Add your own buttons to kick input.stepUp() and stepDown().